# Cannot read cookie data from Cakephp phpunit test

Tags: php, cakephp, cookies, phpunit, cakephp-2.0

I'm using Cakephp's build in test framework to test my controllers. I have a logout function that expires a variety of cookies that are created as the user uses the site. I am trying to read said cookies to determine if a test should pass or not, i.e. to test if the cookie is correctly expired. I have made sure that the cookie component is correctly instantiated, but I cannot read any value back from the cookie that should be there. This is the code that composes the test I am running:

```
public function testLogout() {
    // setup the cookie component
    $collection = new ComponentCollection();
    $this->Cookie = new CookieComponent($collection);

    $result = $this->testAction('/users/logout');
    $cookie_name = Configure::read('tech_cookie_name');
    $cookie_data = $this->Cookie->read($cookie_name);

    debug($cookie_name);

    // cookie data is returning as NULL but I'm expecting some type of value.
    debug($cookie_data);
    debug($result);
    exit;
}
```

I realize that exit is killing the test early, but I'm using it to see if anything is send back from the cookie. I'm not sure why I cannot read any data from a cookie that I know is there. Does anyone know why that might be, or have a solution for how to properly read from cookies in a unit test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cann't read from routes.php Configure::read() in certain cases and it is not a good practice. it will work in localhost but not in live. try to configure your session properly. 
by calling your session from AppController and also from your current Controller (UserController) then you should be able to see it in your testing actions.

```
public $components = array('Session', 'RequestHandler', 'Cookie', ...);
```

if you write your session like this:

```
$this->Session->write('Test.tech_cookie_name', 'tech_cookie_name');
```

then you should be able to read it like this:

```
$this->Session->read('Test.tech_cookie_name');
```